# How can I use an absolute path to my CSS with impatient-mode?

Tags: html, css

I installed [`impatient-mode` through MELPA](http://melpa.org/#/impatient-mode), and I'm having some trouble with the CSS functionality.

If I create a directory called `temp` with an HTML file and a CSS file inside:

```
temp
├── index.html
└── stylesheet.css
```

where `index.html` looks something like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Hello, world!</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css">
<p>Hello, world!
```

then start `simple-httpd` and `impatient-mode`:

```
C-x C-f temp/index.html RET
M-x httpd-serve-directory RET RET
M-x impatient-mode RET
C-x C-f stylesheet.css RET
M-x impatient-mode RET
```

and finally navigate to `http://localhost:8080/imp/live/index.html/` in my browser, I can edit both `index.html` and `stylesheet.css` and see my changes in real time.

However, if I use an absolute path instead:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheet.css">
```

the real-time view doesn't seem to work; I need to reload the HTML every time I edit the CSS.

How can I fix this behavior? Should I simply change the absolute paths to relative paths while I'm working on the CSS, or is there a more convenient solution? Should I submit this as an [issue](https://github.com/netguy204/imp.el/issues)?